# Use Python Subprocess to edit Clang Call Graph Dump Output

Tags: python, subprocess, clang++, call-graph

Is there a way to write over a Clang Dump Call Graph?

I Currently have the following code:

```
static void D() { }
static void Y() { D(); }
static void X() { Y(); }
static void C() { D(); X(); }
static void B() { C(); }
static void S() { D(); }
static void P() { S(); }
static void O() { P(); }
static void N() { O(); }
static void M() { N(); }
static void G() { M(); }
static void A() { B(); G(); }

int main() {
    A();
}
```

I issue this command: clang -Xclang -analyze -Xclang -analyzer-checker=debug.DumpCallGraph 
To get the following output:

```
 --- Call graph Dump --- 
  Function: < root > calls: D Y X C B S P O N M G A main 
  Function: main calls: A 
  Function: A calls: B G 
  Function: G calls: M 
  Function: M calls: N 
  Function: N calls: O 
  Function: O calls: P 
  Function: P calls: S 
  Function: S calls: D 
  Function: B calls: C 
  Function: C calls: D X 
  Function: X calls: Y 
  Function: Y calls: D 
  Function: D calls:
```

I want to use python to parse through the output to get an output that appears like this:

```
Function: [A] calls: [B] [G] 
Function: [G] calls: [M]
etc...
```

So far I'm working on an example code that uses subprocesses to run the command through python.

```
    import re
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

    word = "Function"
    p = Popen(["clang -Xclang -analyze -Xclang -analyzer-checker=debug.DumpCallGraph <filename>"], stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    for line in p.stdout: 
        if word in line:
           for _ in range(re.findall(r"\w+", line).count(word)):
               print("something something", line)
        else:
            print("nope")
```

I'm open to all suggestions for a correct output!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please check update!